# Image not appearing in canvas - sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This works great on all of my tests, but on the live system, I have a problem.

There are three separate but identical canvases.  They are all initially painted with 640x480 jpg images.  The third is then updated every second with a new 640x480 jpg image.

For some reason, the original static image for the third canvas - and that canvas only - doesn't load from the live server, only on the tests.

Here's the html:

```
    <div style="padding: 1vw;">
    <a href="/virtualscribe" class="camLink">
        <div class="camDiv">
            <div class="camBox" id="picBoxLeft">
                <canvas id="canvasLeft" class="camBorder"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/videos" class="camLink">
        <div class="camDiv">
            <div class="camBox" id="picBoxCenter">
                <canvas id="canvasCenter" class="camBorder"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="camDiv">
        <div class="camBox" id="picBoxRight">
            <canvas id="canvasRight" class="camBorder"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
    <style>
    .camBox {
        max-width: 28vw;
        width: 28vw;
        height: 21vw;
        max-height: 21vw;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .camDiv {
        padding: 1.5vw;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .camBorder {
        border: 0.6vw solid #fe890f;
        border-top-left-radius: 3.3vw;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3.3vw;
    }
    .camLink {
        color: transparent;
    }
</style>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
    var refreshTimer;
    var imgLiveCam;

    function drawPictureBox(img, canvas, text) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.globalAlpha = 0.6;
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(244,121,32)";
        context.fillRect(0, canvas.height * 0.67, canvas.width, canvas.height * 0.33);
        context.globalAlpha = 1;
        var maxWidth = canvas.width;
        var x = canvas.width / 2;
        var y = canvas.height * 0.85;
        context.font = canvas.width / 12 + 'px Oswald';
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.strokeText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
        context.fillStyle = 'white';
        context.fillText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
    };
    function drawCamBox(img, logo, canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.globalAlpha = 0.6;
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(244,121,32)";
        context.fillRect(0, canvas.height * 0.67, canvas.width, canvas.height * 0.33);
        var eSize = canvas.height / 10;
        context.globalAlpha = 1;
        context.drawImage(logo, 2, canvas.height * 0.67 - eSize, eSize, eSize);
        var now = new Date();
        var text = now.toLocaleDateString() + " " + now.toLocaleTimeString();
        var maxWidth = canvas.width * 0.33;
        var x = canvas.width - 10 - maxWidth;
        var y = canvas.height * 0.67 - 10;
        context.font = maxWidth / 10 + "px Arial";
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
        context.fillStyle = 'white';
        context.fillText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
        text = 'View Our Production Floor';
        context.textAlign = "center";
        maxWidth = canvas.width;
        x = canvas.width / 2;
        y = canvas.height * 0.85;
        context.font = canvas.width / 12 + 'px Oswald';
        context.strokeText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
        context.fillText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
    }
    function addResizeListener(fn) {
        if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent('onresize', fn)
        } else if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('resize', fn, true);
        };
    }
    function initCam() {
        var imgLeft = new Image();
        imgLeft.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasLeft");
            var picBox = document.getElementById("picBoxLeft");
            var drawFn = function () {
                canvas.height = picBox.clientHeight;
                canvas.width = picBox.clientWidth;
                drawPictureBox(imgLeft, canvas, 'Looking for a Scribe?');
            };
            drawFn();
            addResizeListener(drawFn);
        }
        var imgCenter = new Image();
        imgCenter.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasCenter");
            var picBox = document.getElementById("picBoxCenter");
            var drawFn = function () {
                canvas.height = picBox.clientHeight;
                canvas.width = picBox.clientWidth;
                drawPictureBox(imgCenter, canvas, 'Watch In-Depth Videos');
            };
            drawFn();
            addResizeListener(drawFn);
        }
        imgLiveCam = new Image();
        var logo = new Image();
        logo.src = "e.png";
        imgLiveCam.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasRight");
            var picBox = document.getElementById("picBoxRight");
            var drawFn = function () {
                canvas.height = picBox.clientHeight;
                canvas.width = picBox.clientWidth;
                drawCamBox(imgLiveCam, logo, canvas);
            };
            drawFn();
            imgLiveCam.onload = drawFn;
            addResizeListener(drawFn);
        }
        imgLeft.src = "scribe.jpg";
        imgCenter.src = "doc-with-spine.jpg";
        imgLiveCam.src = "camloading.jpg";
        refreshTimer = setTimeout(refresh, 499);
    }
    function refresh() {
        clearTimeout(refreshTimer);
        imgLiveCam.src = "http://cams.edataservices.com/17fcam.jpg?t=" + new Date().getTime();
        refreshTimer = setTimeout(refresh, 1009);
    }
```

Any idea why the third canvas starts out blank most of the time?

Comment: Is it always the same picture that do not show? Are you starting from the same image each time you load the page? It sounds like one or more images are just not at the url u r trying to get.

Comment: I agree with ArchLicher, try adding a listener to `Image.onerror` to check if the image has loaded or not. BTW I cant see `refresh` called from anywhere but timeout so you don't need to clear a timeout once it has timedout

Comment: Actually, yes, it is always the same image.  I'm trying to load a "default" image that will appear until the updating image (live image) is loaded later in the refresh.

I ended up putting in a 1500 msec delay before starting the updates, and now it appears to work consistently.  I think the update request was going out before the first image was loaded, which confused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a longer delay before starting the refresh cycle, the browsers had more time to load the initial, "default" image.  I set it at 1500ms, and now it is pretty reliable.

(Thanks for the help...)